# How to add firestore rule that require a request's array not to be empty

Tags: arrays, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm running a web application that search on firestore given a list of tags.
I want to prevent requests with empty or null tags (i.e. search for all Items, paginated or not).
Therefore I created the following firestore rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if false
    }
    
    match /Items/{itemId} {
      allow read: if (resource.data.visibility == 'public');
      allow write: if false
    }
    
    match /Items/{restOfPath=**} {
      // allow read: if request.query.limit <= 30
      allow read: if resource.data.tags != null && resource.data.visibility == 'public'
    }
  }
}
```

I run it with the firebase emulator
And this is a mocha test:

```js
it.only('expect succeeding search for items by tags', async () => {

    const createdDocsIds = await setupTestData({ visibility: 'public' });
    const unvisibilityIds = await setupTestData({ visibility: 'private' });

    const db = getFirestore(null); // Meaning the user is not authenticated
    const query = db.collection('Items');
    const data = await (query.where('tags', 'array-contains-any', ['video'])).get();
    const result = getDocsFromData(data);
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(result);
    expect(result.length).to.equal(2);
});
```

According to several tutorials I saw, the `resource.data.tags` refer to the content that is currently exist on the DB (i.e. firestore) and in order to make such rules to limit the request I need to use the following rule:

```js
match /Items/{restOfPath=**} {
  // allow read: if request.query.limit <= 30
  allow read: if request.resource.data.tags != null && request.resource.data.tags.length > 0 && request.resource.data.visibility == 'public'
}
```

My problems are:

1. There is no such content `request.resource`. I created a rule that pass if it is not null and it fails.
2. The condition `resource.data.tags.length` > 0 does not work although the `resource.data.tags` != null does which means the tags arrived